# Call a warm up function once before all of the unittests in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to call a warm-up function once before executing all of the unittest.
Consider an example:

```
import unittest

def addnumbers(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c

class Testaddnumbers(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 10
        print(f'a set up to {self.a}')
        
    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(addnumbers(self.a,2,3), 15)

    def test2(self):
        self.assertEqual(addnumbers(self.a,5,6), 21)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What I want is to set `self.a` to 10, and then run two tests (test1 and test2). However, I can see that `setUp()` function was called 2 times (one for each test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setUpClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass):

```
class Testaddnumbers(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.a = 10
        print(f"a set up to {cls.a}")

    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(addnumbers(self.a, 2, 3), 15)

    def test2(self):
        self.assertEqual(addnumbers(self.a, 5, 6), 21)
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I did not notice the different names of SetUp and SetUpClass methods when I read the docs.